# Circular chemical reaction cascade

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemistry

I am trying to use `tikz-cd` package to draw circular chemical reaction cascade. Here is what I have tried so far

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, tikz-cd}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
    % nodes
    \node (origin) at (0,0) {};
    \node (a) at (4,0) {A};
    \node (b) at (2.828,2.828) {B};
    \node (c) at (0,4) {C};
    \node (d) at (-2.828,2.828) {D};
    \node (e) at (-4, 0) {E};
    \node (f) at (-2.828,-2.828) {F};
    \node (g) at (0,-4) {G};
    \node (h) at (2.828, -2.828) {H};

    \draw (0, 0) circle [radius = 4cm]; %This element for illustration
    \draw [->] (a) to[bend right=45]  (b);
    \draw [->] (b) to[bend right=45]  (c);
    \draw [->] (c) to[bend right=45]  (d);
    \draw [->] (d) to[bend right=45]  (e);
    \draw [->] (e) to[bend right=45]  (f);
    \draw [->] (f) to[bend right=45]  (g);
    \draw [->] (g) to[bend right=45]  (h);
    \draw [->] (h) to[bend right=45]  (a);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

Which results into something like following,
[image]

However, I want arrows to be in circular manner. (*Aligned to circle which I have drawn for illustration purpose*). Also finally I am trying to get reaction cascade like this,
[image]

Any help will be appreciated ! I tried looking at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351158/drawing-circular-diagram-with-arrows) post but wasn't sure how to implement here.

Comment: Your arrows `bend right` too much. Try to reduce the value, and the arrows will be more circular. Also, instead of positioning nodes with cartesian coordinates, you could place them by polar coordinates. Furthermore, you seem not to be using `tikz-cd` syntax, but the underlying `tikz` one.

Comment: @Astrinus, you were right ! `bend right=15`works perfect. :)